# Creating a search field

Tags: php, mysql, search

So i'm working on this site and i just added a search button.
Everything works fine when i use a simple search query like

```
SELECT `student_id` FROM `student` WHERE `username` LIKE 'jo%' OR `firstname` LIKE 'jo%' OR `lastname` LIKE 'jo%' OR `surname` LIKE 'jo%' OR `email` LIKE 'jo%'
```

This will return all id with a name that matches john from a database by looking at the fields 'username', firstname, lastname, and so on.

Th problem however is, when the user inserts a space between the search parameter (which in essence means he is searching a student by both names), the result is nothing.

I figured that this is because the it is looking for the search parameter (say, 'john doe') independently in each field.

How do i work around this.

Comment: You switch to using a `FULLTEXT` search, which makes such searching trivially easy: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure how you would like to treat these, you could add this to your WHERE clause to also search against the firstname and lastname fields with a space in between them.

```
CONCAT(`firstname`, ' ', `lastname`) LIKE 'jo%'
```

or you may want to drop the wildcard and do an exact search.

```
CONCAT(`firstname`, ' ', `lastname`) = 'jo'
```

Comment: Thank you Tom and Marc B , let me try both options and see how everything pans out

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get into searching/matching across multiple columns, you really need to look into MySQL full text search capabilities.  See this link for documentation to get you started:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-natural-language.html

This will scale much better than trying to `LIKE` across a bunch of columns.

Comment: Does the fulltext way mean I have to go back to the design of my database structure?

Comment: @JohnKariuki Yes. At least with regards to the indexes on your columns. It also would require that you use MyISAM as storage engine for the table, so if you currently have InnoDB table and rely on specific InnoDB functionality, you would need to possibly rethink your schema more throughly.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM student 
    WHERE username LIKE REPLACE(username, ' ', '') = REPLACE("Twitt er", ' ', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could assume that the existence of a space means that the user is searching for a first/last name combination. (in fact your UI could state this).

then use

```
$name = split(' ' , $incoming);
```

Then you create a conditional check to whether $name[1] exists, and then work out whether to search for

```
$where_clause = WHERE firstname = $name[0] AND lastname = $name[1];
```

If that fails, fall back to:

```
$where_clause = WHERE firstname = $name[0]
```

or

```
$where_clause = WHERE lastname = $name[1]
```

and so on.

Then use it like:

```
SELECT `student_id` FROM `student` . $where_clause
```

This is somewhat pseudocodish, but you get the picture I hope.

There are more elegant ways of achieving such an `sql-builder`, but I offer it as a way of illustrating how you could start to think about it -- the "use FULLTEXT" comments aside.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this:

1) As you are trying to

`

```
     $search_term= "Mike Brant";
      $term_part = preg_split('/ /', $search_term);
     /*
      term_part[0]=Mike
      term_part[1]=Brant
    */
     foreach($term_part as $value){
    $like. = " `username` LIKE '".$value."%' OR `firstname` LIKE '".$value."%' OR `lastname` LIKE '".$value."%' OR `surname` LIKE '".$value."%' OR `email` LIKE '".$value."%' OR "
    }
    $like = substr($like, 0, -3);
    $sql = "SELECT `student_id` FROM `student` WHERE ".$like.";
`
```

2)  Use FULLTEXT search table engine MYISAM
   learn more about [FULLText](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-natural-language.html)

FULLTEXT is best option for search applications